# Othogonal functions over an interval

Tags: integration, orthogonality

Suppose I have a function g(x).  How do I find a function f(x) that is orthogonal to g over the interval [a,b]?

Answer (score 1):

The only condition you have is that $\inf_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$. Given any function g, there exist many functions, f, that satisfy that.

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Spring09/legendre.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let $g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous $(g \neq 0)$ and let
$$A := \int_a^b g(x)^2 dx$$
Let $h : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous function $(h \neq g)$ and define $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
$$f(x) := h(x) - \Big(\frac{1}{A}\int_a^b h(x)g(x)dx \Big) g(x)$$
By construction it holds:
$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = \int_a^b h(x)g(x)dx - \int_a^b h(x)g(x)dx = 0$$

The continuity assumption in not really necessary, it suffices that $g,h \in L^2([a,b])$